# SQL Server: store image in local variable

Tags: sql-server, image

I'm wondering if what I need to do is in the realm of possibility. I have a column of type `image` in a table. What I would like to do is store that value into a local variable in a stored procedure after retrieval, for inserting into a temp table for ultimately retrieving in my result set. Trouble is, you cannot declare a local variable of type `image`.

Any sort of conversion function exist, where I can accomplish what I would like to do?

Comment: Don't use `image`. Its been deprecated since at least 2008, possibly even 2005. Use `varbinary(MAX)`.

Comment: You would be able to `CONVERT` image type to VARBINARY, preferably `VARBINARY(MAX)`

Comment: Why do you want to take an image from a table, then insert it into a temp to just later select it again? Why not just select it when you actually need it? And as Larnu said, the image datatype has been deprecated since 2005.